# Nginx doesn't route according to my custom rules

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Problem**:
Nginx doesn't route traffic based on the rule I have defined in a separate config file, and just displays the default 404 response.

**Context**:
I have a small middleware application written in Go that provides a simple response to GET requests. The application is deployed on port 8080:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
ok
```

I wish to write an Nginx configuration that allows me to route calls from **/api** to **localhost:8080**, which would allow me to do the following

```
$ curl localhost/api
ok
```

To achieve this, I have written the following config:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/custom-nginx-rules**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

I have also created a softlink in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/** for the above file

```
$ ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jan 19 16:42 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Feb 20 14:56 custom-nginx-rules -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/custom-nginx-rules
```

The rest of the setup is vanilla Nginx, nothing is changed.
Despite this simple setup, I get a 404 when making the following call:

```
$ curl localhost/api
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Other info**: the following are nginx packages installed on my system (running on raspberry pi)

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nginx

ii  libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam      1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        PAM authentication module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext       1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        WebDAV missing commands support for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-echo          1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Bring echo and more shell style goodies to Nginx 
ii  libnginx-mod-http-geoip         1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        GeoIP HTTP module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-image-filter  1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        HTTP image filter module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter   1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Substitution filter module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair 1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Nginx Upstream Fair Proxy Load Balancer
ii  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter   1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        XSLT Transformation module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-mail               1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Mail module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-stream             1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Stream module for Nginx
ii  nginx                           1.10.3-1+deb9u1              all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                    1.10.3-1+deb9u1              all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-full                      1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```

I also require that this setup is independent of any host or server names. It should do the routing regardless of host.

Comment: you should run `nginx -T` and see if your config is in fact being loaded. Also check the nginx error log, which may help tell you if it's the origin or nginx itself returning the 404

Comment: `nginx -T` confirms that my custom rules are being loaded, and the error log is empty

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full configuration, it seems like it could be the case that the default nginx `server` block is accepting the request, rather than yours. You can try to fix this by changing the listen line to be:

`listen 80 default_server;`

You can also confirm that this is the case by adding a `server_name` and curling using that:

`server_name api.example.com;`

Then:
`curl -H "Host: api.example.com" http://localhost/api`

If that works, the issue is definitely the default_server handling.

From the [NGINX docs on server selection](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html):

> In this configuration nginx tests only the request’s header field “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port. In the configuration above, the default server is the first one — which is nginx’s standard default behaviour. It can also be set explicitly which server should be default, with the default_server parameter in the listen directive: